# Does my question about a Linux program that does signal processing belong here?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I am looking for signal processing software, that runs well under Ubuntu 10.04: [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/how-do-i-convert-my-old-pc-in-a-data-logging-and-presentation-terminal). Does it belong here, or at [Signal Processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) or at [Electrical Engineering SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), or maybe somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For suggestions of software that fit your purpose and how to install it, I think here would be adequate.

However, implementation of algorithms would be better fit at Stack Overflow (for coding-related questions) or DSP.SE (for math-related questions; I don't know how well they take programming questions).